# React table - rearranging - group by keep position of column

Tags: react-table

I'm using the useGroupBy hook to group my react-table table. However when grouping the default behaviour is to group re-arrange the columns in the table but I wan't to keep them in the same position, do you know how to do this with the optional useGroupByHook?

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-tree-bq19p?file=/src/App.js

When pressing groupby i.e age it will move age to the left..

Before grouping:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's some property on column called : groupedIndex - first column that is beign grouped has got 0 index and other columns -1, I have tried to change it manually but It's not working, maybe you will figure out how to do that

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the ordering during table rendering:

```
 const fixColumnOrder = (cells) => columns.map(column => cells.find(cell => cell.column.id === column.id))
```

```
 <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
   {fixColumnOrder(row.cells).map((cell) => {
     return (
       <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
          {cell.render('Cell')}
       </td>
     )
   })}
 </tr>
```

You need to do the same trick for the headers